# Deployment error on my netbeans console when run web project on j2ee platform

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans-8, glassfish-4

Can anyone help me please because I am blocking on this point.

My netbeans console shows :

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\Amirou\\NetBeansProjects\\pro_jpa -Dnb.internal.action.name=run -Ddirectory.deployment.supported=true -DforceRedeploy=false -Dnb.wait.for.caches=true -Dbrowser.context=C:\\Users\\Amirou\\NetBeansProjects\\pro_jpa run
init:

deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:

In-place deployment at C:\Users\Amirou\NetBeansProjects\pro_jpa\build\web
GlassFish Server 4.1.1, deploy, null, false

C:\Users\Amirou\NetBeansProjects\pro_jpa\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1050: The module has not been deployed.

See the server log for details.

BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

I didn't understand from where it appears.

Comment: Have you read the server logs ?

Comment: Paste the logs in a pastebin